# Why does this array exist even after it is freed?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I am freeing the memory allocated to `b`. But I was under the impression that memory allocated dynamically disappears after you "free" it. But I am not getting any errors with this code and I can still access the original values assigned to elements of `b` even after freeing it. How is this possible ? What should I do to completely erase `b` ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int i, imax;
    int *b;

    imax=5;
    b=malloc(sizeof(int)*imax);

    for (i=0; i < imax; i++)
    {
        b[i]=i*i;
        printf("%d ",b[i]);
    }

    free(b);
    printf("\n memory freed \n");

    for (i=0; i < imax; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

result after compiling with gcc and running it

```
0 1 4 9 16 
 memory freed 
0 1 4 9 16
```

Comment: There are ~5000 dups of this question.

Comment: In addition to Drew's comment of avoiding reading free memory. It's generally good practice to set the pointer to null after a free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of *undefined behavior*. There are many different possibilities, including:

1. The memory read is the exact same, because the C library just marked it as free without touching it
2. The memory read is garbage, because something else reused that newly-freed block
3. Your program crashes, because the address is no longer acceptable.
4. Your computer launches a nuclear missile headed for Antarctica, because hey, *anything* is possible with undefined behavior!

So please, for the sake of the cute little penguins, avoid reading freed memory!

Answer (score 0):

Accessing an object after it has been free'd with `free` invokes undefined behavior. Don't do it.

That is:

```
for (i=0; i < imax; i++)
{
    printf("%d ",b[i]);  // invokes undefined behavior!
}
```

If you are unlucky nothing will happen but everything can happen from crash to nasal demons.